# Cannot access a variable declared outside a For loop (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, chart.js

I just cannot access a variable declared outside a For loop in Javascript. The For loop is inside an object property, which is inside a Function and it's being used to draw a chart using Chart.Js.

Is there any workaround for it?

## Here comes the code:

```
function chart1Update() {

var string = "['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']"

// bar chart data

var barData = {
labels : [
{% for item in string %} // <==== THE PROBLEM IS RIGHT HERE (string) <====
"{{ item }}",
{% endfor %}
],
datasets : [{
fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
data : [
{% for item in ['1499', '1554', '1661', '1658'] %}
"{{ item }}",
{% endfor %}
]
}
]
}
```

Comment: If you take the % out it should do what you expect. The % looks like a templating library/framework (handlebars perhaps). The code between those symbols in which case will be inserting server side code

Comment: Correct! Thanks for the advise! The model I was using was trying to pull the label from Flask/Python! It would never work haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `{% for item in string %}` does not look like javascript. is that some ruby thing or something? Its looking for the the variable `string` defined in whatever non-javascript language that tag is coming from, and its undefined or uninitialized since it doesn't have access to any javscript variables.

If you make it a JS array (instead of an array declaration inside of a string, as it currently is), You can just assign the js array directly without even looping, ie

```
var string = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']; //no double quotes on the outside
var barData = {
labels : string,
//...
```

The reason your `data` loop does work is because the variable, an array literal, is defined inside of the tag, so it does have access to it.

Comment: I am not used to coding, so I couldn't see this before! Thanks for that. It was actually trying to get the label from Flask on the server side. I would never get this to work this way.

Comment: But now I have something else to solve. My actual variable contains an attribute name pulled from a <div> in HTML. It pulls fine, but when I use this variable as the label I need, it returns split letter by letter. If I put this variable inside square brackets, then everything comes to only one big label. The label value (attribute name) I have is - without quotes "['American felt', 'Dwyer Instruments', 'Astro Chemical', 'Helwig Carbon']". - without square brackets, it draws one bar in the chart for each letter. Using square brackets, one bar for the whole thing inside the double-quotes.

Comment: ah, @JulioSouto just remove the outer double quotes so you end up with `var string = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'];`